# FeignClient not resolving Eureka service name

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

I'm writing a Eureka Client Application using `spring-cloud-starter-openfeign` client. 
Here is my **POM**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>service-registration-and-discovery-client</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>service-registration-and-discovery-client</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As you can see, I'm using spring boot version `2.2.4.RELEASE`
spring-cloud.version `Hoxton.SR1`

This is my application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class ServiceRegistrationAndDiscoveryClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceRegistrationAndDiscoveryClientApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Till herem My client application is getting registered on Eureka service successfully, i can see my applicaiton on Eureka page as well.

Now I've written an interface to call another service, which is registered on Eureka also,

```
@FeignClient("ANOTHER-SERVICE")
public interface SPProxy {

    @PostMapping("/anotherserviceplatform/api/resource/test")
    String testAPI(@RequestBody TestRequestBody request);
}
```

and I'm calling this method from one of my controller. but Feign is not resolving the service-name to It's URL. it is tryign to make http call to

> http://ANOTHER-SERVICE/anotherservice/api/resource/test

instead of calling

> http://192.168.1.1:8080/anotherservice/api/resource/test

and getting timeout exception (Which is obvious). below is the stacktrace

```
2020-01-31 13:03:56.281 ERROR 16693 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.RetryableException: connect timed out executing POST http://ANOTHER-SERVICE/anotherservice/api/resource/test] with root cause

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1248) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1362) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1337) ~[na:na]
    at feign.Client$Default.convertAndSend(Client.java:174) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:77) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.FeignLoadBalancer.execute(FeignLoadBalancer.java:93) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.FeignLoadBalancer.execute(FeignLoadBalancer.java:56) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient$1.call(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:104) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:303) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:287) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:231) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:228) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.drain(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:286) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:144) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:185) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:110) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:80) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.checkPincodeServiceability(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.serviceregistrationanddiscoveryclient.ServiceInstanceRestController.serviceInstancesByApplicationName(ServiceRegistrationAndDiscoveryClientApplication.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
```

EDIT1:
below is my application.properties

```
spring.application.name=test-client
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eurekahost:8761/eureka/
```

Comment: Pls show your `application.yml` (or `application.properties`)

Comment: @amseager application.properties added

Comment: Can you add more information about `ANOTHER-SERVICE` ? Also, is it available if you use raw URL instead of ribbon name in Feign client?

Comment: Yes It is available, even if i use DiscoverClient.getInstances("ANOTHER-SERVICE"), this is returning me the active instance with correct IP and PORT

Comment: I think you also need to add @DiscoveryClient at class ServiceRegistrationAndDiscoveryClientApplication to connect to erureka

Comment: @Vipul didn't work :(

Comment: I saw in the applications.properties, that you have

    spring.application.name=test-client

.That's the name of which one microservice?
Have you tried to change the parameter of FeignClient to 
    @FeignClient("test-client")

.The FeignClient value has to match with the name of the app you are looking for to connect

Comment: @ctorrez04 . I have 2 apps, a client app that is trying to connect to another-service. this applicatino.properties file is for the client application. it's name is test-client. this app trying to connect to another-service

Comment: @AbdulMohsin did you get solution?

Comment: any update on how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 3):

Recently I also faced the same issue. I was kind of able to figure out the root cause of this behavior when working with localhost.

[Screenshot of issue reproduced at local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jihzs.png)

The whole reason for this to happen is that the **eureka server** is unable to resolve the
http://currency-exchange-service/currency-exchange/from/USD/to/INR
to http://localhost:9093/currency-exchange/from/USD/to/INR

if you check your Eureka server dashboard and hover the services registered you will see the hostname that eureka server is pointing as shown in below screenshot. If you hover link (under status column), the hostname we see is not correct which is causing this issue.

[Screenshot of Eureka dashboard, the cause of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFkg4.png)

**Solution:**
Add the below property in your application.properties file of your Eureka client applications
**eureka.instance.hostname=localhost**

in your case please put the appropriate host name.

and that should be it. After making the change restart you client applications.
Go to you Eureka Dashboard again hover the link for you registered applications this should look something like below:

[Screen shot of Eureka server dashboard after making the appropriate changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxj5d.png) .

After making the changes please try and access your  Http request using the feign client. It worked for me.
[Screenshot of the final result with API result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23dXa.png)

Comment: I tried that but still got the same error. Looks like there is some other issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `restTemplate.exchange` from spring automatically

or

```
private String getAnotherServiceBaseAddress() {

        try {

            InstanceInfo info = getEurekaClient().getNextServerFromEureka("another-service", false);
            if (info == null || info.getHomePageUrl() == null)
                return "(default)http://192.168.1.1:8080/anotherservice";
            else
                return info.getHomePageUrl()+"/anotherservice;

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
             return "(default)http://192.168.1.1:8080/anotherservice";
        }
    }

public static EurekaClient getEurekaClient() {
    return applicationContext.getBean(EurekaClient.class);
}
```

finally:

```
HttpGet http = new HttpGet(getAnotherServiceBaseAddress() + "/api/resource/test");
```

Comment: I know i can go with this way. but due to some reason I have to use FeignClient. so that it will take care all the stuff internally and i do not have to make http calls manually.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more reason for that:

1 - Check the application properties it should be like that :

```
spring.application.name=reception-service
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.client.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

2 - Make sure the service name is in **capital letters**, not small letters :
like that :

```
@FeignClient(name = "INSURANCE", path = "/apis/v1/inc")
```

Not like

```
@FeignClient(name = "Insurance", path = "/apis/v1/inc")
```

3 - Add important annotation :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `eureka.client.enabled=true` to application.properties file fixed issue for me

Answer (score 0):

**eureka.instance.hostname=localhost**
add this to your application properties of the feign client service